# Two Column Layout and Single CSS/JS Files

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am a Bootstrap user and have been one for many years now. I am looking to use Semantic UI in a person project and have some questions.

1) Is it possible to get the CSS in one single file and the JS in one single file easily? I don't like having to include a bunch of different files and I want to make sure that all components are included.

2) When it comes to layouts, I was attempting to build a simple two column layout however, every time I shrank the window down in size, the content from the right pane would over lap the content in the left pane. Why is this?

3) Do I have to write my own CSS to build the basic construct of my page(s)?

4) Is it possible with the side bar icon navigation to have the side bar be displayed all the time?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide some code or a fiddle

Comment: lecya: I am really just looking to have my questions answered right now. I removed all of the code that I had previously written inside my application and I am not getting ready to start writing code outside of my application. I did run into another problem: I am unable to build using Gulp. I keep getting tons of errors no matter what I try to do.

Comment: I was able to finally get Semantic built using Gulp however, everything is still in individual files which is not what I want. Any ideas on combining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.my project include CDN

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css">
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

2.this?

Tables will automatically stack their layouts for mobile devices. To disable this behavior, use the unstackable variation or tablet stackable to allow responsive adjustments for tablet.

```
<table class="ui unstackable table">
```

3. is like boostrap . Fisrst you can do 
[Container](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/container.html#/definition)

4.I don't konw what your mean